# Performing Actions Before/After substream in akka-streams 2.4+

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am processing a stream of data from a file that is grouped by a key.  I have created a class with an apply method that can be used to split the stream by key called KeyChanges[T,K].  Before the first item of a substream is processed, I need to retrieve some data from a DB.  Once each substream is completed, I need to emit a message to a queue.  In a standard scala sequence I would do something like this:

```scala
val groups: Map[Key, Seq[Value]] = stream.groupBy(v => v.k)
val groupSummaryF = Future.sequence(groups.map { case (k, group) =>
  retrieveMyData(k).flatMap { data =>
    Future.sequence(group.map(v => process(data, v))).map(
      k -> _.foldLeft(0) { (a,t) =>
        t match {
          case Success(v) => a + 1
          case Failure(ex) =>
            println(s"failure: $ex")
            a
        }
      }
    ).andThen {
      case Success((key,count)) =>
        sendMessage(count,key)
    }
  }
})
```

I would like to do something similar with Akka Streams.  On the data retrieval, I could just cache the data and call the retrieval function for each element but for the queue message, I really do need to know when the substream is completed.  So far I have not seen a way around this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run Stream, and execute action from Sink.

```
val categories = Array("DEBUG", "INFO", "WARN", "ERROR")

// assume we have a stream from file which produces categoryId -> message
val lines = (1 to 100).map(x => (Random.nextInt(categories.length), s"message $x"))

def loadDataFromDatabase(categoryId: Int): Future[String] =
  Future.successful(categories(categoryId))

// assume this emits message to the queue
def emitToQueue(x: (String, Int)): Unit =
  println(s"${x._2} messages from category ${x._1}")

val flow =
  Flow[(Int, String)].
    groupBy(4, _._1).
    fold((0, List.empty[String])) { case ((_, acc), (catId, elem)) =>
      (catId, elem :: acc)
    }.
    mapAsync(1) { case (catId, messages) =>
      // here you load your stuff from the database
      loadDataFromDatabase(catId).map(cat => (cat, messages))
    }. // here you may want to do some more processing
    map(x => (x._1, x._2.size)).
    mergeSubstreams

// assume the source is a file
Source.fromIterator(() => lines.iterator).
via(flow).
to(Sink.foreach(emitToQueue)).run()
```

If you want to run it for multiple files, and report sums once for example, you can do it like that.

```
val futures = (1 to 4).map { x =>
  Source.fromIterator(() => lines.iterator).via(flow).toMat(Sink.seq[(String, Int)])(Keep.right).run()
}
Future.sequence(futures).map { results =>
  results.flatten.groupBy(_._1).foreach { case (cat, xs) =>
    val total = xs.map(_._2).sum
    println(s"$total messages from category $cat")
  }
}
```

As you see, when you run the flow, you get a future. It will contain a materialized value (result of the flow), when it's finished, and you can do with it whatever you want.

Comment: I had a solution that folded the substream into a List but that seemed like it could be susceptible to high memory consumption if a substream is very large.  I found that "alsoTo" can be used after the fold to allow the queue emission, since in my actual use case, there is further summarization of the results being done after the mergeSubstreams.

Comment: If you don't need the values you can fold not to list but to a number. Maybe if you can be more exact what you need and what are the sizes of the data, I can propose better solution.